# htaccess rewrite. always replace the the first part after domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

My main API URL entry point is: https://www.sample-domain.com/abc/  and then I can have URI_REQUESTS which will follow, for e.g.: 

https://www.sample-domain.com**/abc/**

https://www.sample-domain.com**/abc/**?do=something

https://www.sample-domain.com**/abc/**john (with trailing slash or not..) 

I want to be alble always to rewirte to any request which has the first part of the URL diffrent back to /abc/. Examples:

https://www.sample-domain.com**/def/**  (with trailing slash or not..) 

https://www.sample-domain.com**/def/**?do=something or 

https://www.sample-domain.com**/def/**john 

I dont care how many parts the URL will have after the first part ot if it has trailing slashes or any query-strings I alwas want to change the first part following the domain back to /abc/

But certain first parts has to be ignored for examle if it comes in as sample-domain.com/help/ then it should not rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty straight forward:

```
RewriteEngine on
RequestCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/
RequestCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(help|help2|help3)/
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+/(.*)$ /abc/$1 [END,QSA]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).